# MVC checkbox list bounding to model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to collect all the options that the user have selected for a checkbox list. The checkbox list is built using a foreach loop and I have a int[] that I am trying to put the id into. Any help would be great.

View

```
 @{
 int idxFormats = 0;
 foreach (var item in Model.ListOfFormats)
 {
     <div class='col-md-6'>
          <input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="chkFormat" />
          <label asp-for=@item.Selected>@Html.Raw(@item.Name)</label>
          @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.selectedFormats[idxFormats]);
     </div>
     idxFormats++;
  }
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.selectedFormats[idxFormats])
  }
```

Model

```
public List<GenericValues> ListOfFormats { get; set; }
[Display(Name = "At least one 'Format' must be selected")]
public int[] selectedFormats { get; set; }
```

Comment: do you want to use idxFormats as the id or something else like @item.Id ?

Comment: on this model for ListOfFormats I dont have an id can I use the idxFormats and set the value to item.Value

Comment: are you looking for this ?   `id="@idxFormats"`

Comment: where would I add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the Checkbox name to `selectedFormats`

```
<input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="selectedFormats" />
```

Test example:

Model:

```
public class Test
{
    public List<GenericValues> ListOfFormats { get; set; }
    public int[] selectedFormats { get; set; }
}

public class GenericValues
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model Test

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<form method="post">
    @{
        foreach (var item in Model.ListOfFormats)
        {
            <div class='col-md-6'>
                <input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="selectedFormats" />
                <label asp-for=@item.Selected>@Html.Raw(@item.Name)</label>
            </div>
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Test test = new Test
    {
        ListOfFormats = new List<GenericValues>
        {
            new GenericValues
            {
                Name = "A",
                Value = 1,
            },
            new GenericValues
            {
                Name = "B",
                Value = 2,
            },
            new GenericValues
            {
                Name = "C",
                Value = 3,
            }
        }
    };
    return View(test);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(Test test)
{

    return Ok();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are looking to put id as value of your idxFormats  then use this code in your checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="chkFormat" id="@idxFormats" />
```

**Edit:**

I am not so familiar with c#, I tested with minimum code :

```
// Replace the model correct path by yours
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.MyModels.ListOfFormats>


@{
    int idxFormats = 0;
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class='col-md-6'>
            <input type="checkbox" value=@item.Value name="chkFormat" id="@idxFormats"/>
            <label>@Html.Raw(@item.Name)</label>
            
        </div>
        idxFormats++;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: I still get all 0's. in the controller

Comment: No the selected checkbox values needs to be sent to the controller not display on psge